# Create a DataFrame from a dictionary with list of dict's in multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas

Instead of normalizing twice(creating 2 df's for 1 dictionary) and merging it, is there any other efficient way to create a DataFrame from the below data directly?

**Data:**

```
dummy_data = {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3list": [
        {
            "key3nestedkey1": "val3list1nested1",
            "key3nestedkey2": "val3list1nested2"
        },
        {
            "key3nestedkey1": "val3list2nested1",
            "key3nestedkey2": "val3list2nested2"
        }
    ],
    "key4list": [
        {
            "key4nestedkey1": "val4list1nested1",
            "key4nestedkey2": "val4list1nested2"
        },
        {
            "key4nestedkey1": "val4list2nested1",
            "key4nestedkey2": "val4list2nested2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
key3_df = pd.json_normalize(dummy_data, "key3list", ["key1", "key2"])
key4_df = pd.json_normalize(dummy_data, "key4list", ["key1", "key2"])

df = pd.merge(key3_df, key4_df, on=["key1", "key2"])
```

**Expected & Actual Output:**

```
>>> df

    key3nestedkey1      key3nestedkey2      key1    key2    key4nestedkey1      key4nestedkey2
0   val3list1nested1    val3list1nested2    val1    val2    val4list1nested1    val4list1nested2
1   val3list1nested1    val3list1nested2    val1    val2    val4list2nested1    val4list2nested2
2   val3list2nested1    val3list2nested2    val1    val2    val4list1nested1    val4list1nested2
3   val3list2nested1    val3list2nested2    val1    val2    val4list2nested1    val4list2nested2
```

Comment: Looks like the asymmetry in the structure si tripping previously diclosed methods

Comment: HI, are you sure the expected output is correct? Why are values in `key4nestedkey1` and `key4nestedkey2` columns not ordered the same way as in `key3nestedkey1` and `key3nestedkey2` columns, since `key3list` and `key4list` are the same kind of lists?

Comment: @Laurent Yes, the expected output is true, basically, the output needs to contain all the unique combinations of `key3list` and `key4list`. In my sample input, `key3list` contains 2 elements and `key4list` 2 elements, so a total of 4 unique combinations are 4 rows and that's why the `key4nestedkey1` and `key4nestedkey2` columns are not ordered in the same way.